# Why are some entries omitted in the eigenvectors output of princomp function in R?

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to manually produce the PCA used in this [webpage](http://yatani.jp/teaching/doku.php?id=hcistats:pca), hence:

```
Price <- c(6,7,6,5,7,6,5,6,3,1,2,5,2,3,1,2)
Software <- c(5,3,4,7,7,4,7,5,5,3,6,7,4,5,6,3)
Aesthetics <- c(3,2,4,1,5,2,2,4,6,7,6,7,5,6,5,7)
Brand <- c(4,2,5,3,5,3,1,4,7,5,7,6,6,5,5,7)
data <- data.frame(Price, Software, Aesthetics, Brand)
```

now the example uses `pca <- princomp(data, cor = T)` which I'm currenty not trying to argue but just follow:

```
R <- cor(data)
e <- eigen(R)$vectors
row.names(e) <- colnames(data)
colnames(e) <- paste("PC", 1:ncol(e), sep = "")
d <- as.matrix(data - colMeans(data))
pc <- d %*% e
```

this results with the following PCA formulae:

```
                  PC1        PC2        PC3         PC4
Price      -0.5229138 0.00807487  0.8483525 -0.08242604
Software   -0.1771390 0.97675554 -0.1198660 -0.01423081
Aesthetics  0.5965260 0.13369503  0.2950727 -0.73431229
Brand       0.5825287 0.16735905  0.4229212  0.67363855
```

but for some reason which I can't fully understand, `princomp` is omitting three components from the PC formulae:

```
           Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Price      -0.523         0.848       
Software   -0.177  0.977 -0.120       
Aesthetics  0.597  0.134  0.295 -0.734
Brand       0.583  0.167  0.423  0.674
```

I can somehow accept the omission of `Price` for `PC2` as it's smaller than 0.01, but what about `Price` and `Software` for `PC4`?

The same applies for princomp for Covariance- mine is:

```
> eigen(cov(data))$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.5957661 -0.3786184  0.7064672 -0.05113761
[2,] -0.1085472 -0.8342628 -0.5401678 -0.02101742
[3,]  0.6053008 -0.2675111  0.3179391 -0.67894297
[4,]  0.5166152 -0.2984819  0.3286908  0.73210631
```

`princomp`'s:

```
           Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Price      -0.596 -0.379  0.706       
Software   -0.109 -0.834 -0.540       
Aesthetics  0.605 -0.268  0.318 -0.679
Brand       0.517 -0.298  0.329  0.732
```

when I've compared my cov-based PCA to `prcomp` it fit, so I suppose this one went okay, but if I need to use R instead of C (if for example X columns are on different scales) then using `princomp` raises a few doubts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `as it's smaller than 0.01, but what about Price and Software for PC4?` Maybe the printout cut-value is 0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3277/ttnphns) pointed, that's only due to a 0.1 default printing cutoff (the underlying object has all the values in it).

---

Reading the [`princomp` function details](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/princomp.html):

> The print method for these objects prints the results in a nice format
>   and the plot method produces a scree plot (screeplot). There is also a
>   biplot method.

This leads us to a [`print` method for `loadings`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/loadings.html), with defaults:

```
print(x, digits = 3, cutoff = 0.1, sort = FALSE, ...)
```

So try:

```
print(pca$loadings, cutoff = 0)

#Loadings:
#           Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#Price      -0.523  0.008  0.848 -0.082
#Software   -0.177  0.977 -0.120 -0.014
#Aesthetics  0.597  0.134  0.295 -0.734
#Brand       0.583  0.167  0.423  0.674
```